# How to make p:messages keep messages until errors are fixed

Tags: validation, jsf-2, primefaces, message

i have validation for three components in a dialog, onblur of the components as follows:

```
<p:message for="idEstNumOfUser" display="icon" id="msgEstNumOfUser" />
<p:inputText id="idEstNumOfUser"
        placeholder="Estimated Number of Users"
        value="#{mybean.estimatedUserCount}" required="true" requiredMessage="Estimated Number of Users Is Required"
        maxlength="8" title="Estimated Number of Users"
        validatorMessage="Please enter digits only for 'Estimated Number of Users'"
        converterMessage="Please enter digits only for 'Estimated Number of Users'">
        <f:convertNumber />
<p:ajax event="blur" update=":betasignup:msgEstNumOfUser" />
</p:inputText>


<p:message for="idTxtFirstName" display="icon" id="msgFirstName" />
<p:inputText id="idTxtFirstName" placeholder="First Name"
    value="#{mybean.firstName}" required="true"
    requiredMessage="First Name Is Required" maxlength="100"
    title="First Name">
    <p:ajax event="blur" update=":betasignup:msgFirstName" />
</p:inputText>

<p:message for="idTxtLastName" display="icon" id="msgLastName" />
<p:inputText id="idTxtLastName" placeholder="Last Name"
    value="#{mybean.lastName}" required="true"
    requiredMessage="Last Name Is Required" maxlength="100"
    title="Last Name">
    <p:ajax event="blur" update=":betasignup:msgLastName" />
</p:inputText>

<p:messages id="messages"  autoUpdate="true"/>
```

my bean is has view scope.

**CASE:** when leaving first field empty and navigating to second field p:messages display message for first field, and when leaving second field empty and navigating to third field, p:messages clears messages for first field and displays only message for second field, and i want it to preserve old message (and remove the error message in case only error is fixed) and display both validation messages since first field and second field currently have validation errors.

**EDIT: Dialog code**

```
<h:form id="betasignup" title="#{msg['betasignup.text']}">
            <p:dialog id="dlgSignUp" widgetVar="signUpDialog" resizable="false"
                modal="true" header="#{msg['betasignup.header']}" styleClass="sign-up-dialog">
```

how i show the dialog:

```
<p:commandLink id="iam_interested2" styleClass="iam_interested"
                        oncomplete="signUpDialog.show()"
                        actionListener="#{myBean.init()}"
                        update=":betasignup">
```

please advise, thanks.

Comment: I completely missed the dialog part. You should include the surrounding dialog code. Is the dialog inside a `<h:form/>` or it has it's own? Is it `dynamic` and how is it updated (`visible="true/false"`?)

Comment: @kolossus, i added the dialog code in the post.

Comment: Set each ajax update tag with `process="@form"`. I suspect the reason why a validation message is displayed for only a single component at a time is that each ajax request only processes a single component. As a result, only one component will ever fail validation at a single time and only one validation message will be queued. By setting each `<p:ajax process="@form"/>` you'll ensure that each component in the form goes thru validation during processing and their respective validators will kick in.

Comment: Of course for this to work properly without affecting any other component in the view, you'll have to bring the dialog outside of the current form and put a separate `<h:form/>` inside it.

Comment: Your question is sound, but why this strange approach of duplicating messages into `<p:messages>`? I'm not seeing a standard solution either, or you must really put some mess in `process` and `update` attributes.

Comment: @BalusC, i want to have p:message beside the component to display error icon and p:messages at the end of the form to display the error message itself, this is the requested requirement.

Comment: @kolossus, thanks a lot for the trick,process="@form" solved the issue.

Comment: This also processes and validates all other inputs the user didn't went along, is this really what you needed? It's just strange to see validation messages to popup for inputs the user didn't tab into yet.

Comment: @BalusC, i want to keep old messages onblur and add new messages to it.

Comment: i am having an issue in the case if i have server side listener on ajax blut `<p:ajax event="blur" process="@form"  listener="#{myBean.isEmailExist()}" update=":betasignup:msgEmail" />` here the server side listener is not invoked unless i use @this

Comment: Yes, I know that, but the `process="@form"` doesn't solve precisely that, it's therefore strange to see you saying that it solved it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set **each ajax update** tag with `process="@form"`. I suspect the reason why a validation message is displayed for only a single component at a time is that each ajax request only processes a single component. As a result, only one component will ever fail validation at a single time and only one validation message will be queued. By setting each  you'll ensure that each component in the form goes thru validation during processing and their respective validators will kick in.

Comment: isn't option1 should be used while redirecting to another view, also where to put this code exactly in my bean since some of the error messages are generated by JSF and some of them i add explicitly from backing bean.

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh, you're right. I'm recommending (1) as a path to root cause diagnosis. My thinking is that something is clearing the queued messages during the ajax requests. I can't say exactly what or why that is happening, but the solution to ensuring that messages are not wiped as a result of request processing is (1). You can use either of the methods; As you're already manually queuing messages, you can use the backing bean option I recommended

Comment: where exactly to put the code in backing bean, in init method ?

Comment: in the example i don't manually generate faces messages, they are generated automatically by the required attribute, so in this case where to use above code ?

Comment: i tried all the suggested solutions with no luck, still getting same behavior.

Comment: `redisplay="true"` doesn't do what you think it does. Real use case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317673/prevent-pmessages-component-from-showing-messages-which-are-already-shown-in-p/

Comment: @kolossus, process="@form" still has one issue if the blur event has server side listener, this listener is not invoked.

Comment: @kolossus, this is the case `<p:ajax event="blur" process="@form"  listener="#{myBean.isEmailExist()}" update=":betasignup:msgEmail" />`here the server side listener is not invoked unless i use @this

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh - it looks like a bug with Primefaces, according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10287115/1530938) and a handful of other related questions

Comment: @kolossus not at all, do you have any workarounds for this bug ?

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh - none. It might not be a bug, I can understand why it works this way. The PF team might have thought it was wasteful to fire an ajax event that submits an entire form for `blur`. As an alternative, you can try the `keyup` event